# this.setState does not update in Child when using a callback function to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a Select Form Child Component from which the user can choose multiple options. Every time the user makes a choice, a function handleChange is executed which calls the function changeExport from parent(passed as a prop to the child). changeExport then updates the parent state and handleChange finishes by updating the child state. The problem is that if the parent state is updated, the child state is not, but if I comment out the line which updates the parent state, child state is updated just fine.

This is the Parent.

```
class ExtendedTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // columnJSON el format is { title: str, field: str, export: bool }
    this.state = { dataJSON: [], columnJSON: [] }
    this.changeExport = this.changeExport.bind(this)
  }
  changeExport(titles){
    const newColumnJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.columnJSON));
    newColumnJSON.forEach(col => {
      if (titles.indexOf(col.title) >= 0) {
        col.export = true
      }
      else {
        col.export = false
      }
    })
    this.setState({ columnJSON: newColumnJSON })
  }
  render(){return(
  ....
  <MultipleSelect names={this.state.columnJSON.map(el=>el.title)}   export={this.changeExport} />
  )}
```

This is the child.

```
class  MultipleSelect extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          names:this.props.names,
          column:[]}
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)


    }

    handleChange(event){
        const arr = event.target.value.slice()
        this.setState({column:arr})
        this.props.export(arr)
    }
    render() {  return(
    <div>
        <FormControl>
        <InputLabel >Tag</InputLabel>
        <Select
            multiple
            value={this.state.column}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            input={<Input />}
            renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}
            MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
            {this.state.names.map(col => (
            <MenuItem key={col} value={col}>
                <Checkbox checked={
                  this.state.column.indexOf(col) > -1}/>
                <ListItemText primary={col} />
            </MenuItem>
            ))}
        </Select>
        </FormControl>

    </div>
    )};
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing here—copying props to state—is [warned against in the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state) for this reason.

The linked page offers a number of alternatives. In your case I think you would be best served by making `MultipleSelect` a controlled component by eliminating state entirely and relying solely on props passed in. This might look something like this:

```
class MultipleSelect extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel>Tag</InputLabel>
          <Select
            multiple
            value={this.props.selected}
            onChange={this.props.handleChange}
            input={<Input />}
            renderValue={selected => selected.join(", ")}
            MenuProps={MenuProps}
          >
            {this.props.options.map(col => (
              <MenuItem key={col} value={col}>
                <Checkbox checked={this.props.selected.indexOf(col) > -1} />
                <ListItemText primary={col} />
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```